# Load Image from Remote Server

Tags: asp.net

I want to display image in image control but the image is on the different server.
My application is Intranet based application. My image is stored on "C:\Project\Images\img123.jpg" and my server name is "MyServer".
Can any one send me the code to display image in to the image control?
I appreciate if any one help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be displayed properly in a browser the image has to reside on a web server. So you could either run a web server on the remote machine and then specify the URL to the image or copy them on the local web server.